# Align HeaderCell in RowCreated

Tags: asp.net, text-alignment

I need to align-center HeaderCell I am adding in Gridview_RowCreated event

```
        HeaderCell.Style.Value = "center";
        GridView3.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

```
   protected void GridView3_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            HeaderCell.Text = "";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);


            HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "Monday";
            HeaderCell.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            HeaderCell.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            HeaderCell.Style.Value = "center";
            GridView3.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;

            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
```

I am trying to center the text "Monday". It's in a columnSpan=2.

HeaderCell.Style.Value = "center";
GridView3.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

Don't work.

Comment: Have a look at this? Particularly, the last answer.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d521cfc5-5f29-4af9-869f-0da0d9c866bd/datagridview-header-center-align-why-does-my-code-keep-getting-changed?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Bleh didn't seem to work for me, or I implemented it wrong. I made sure it was out of the cell loop.  just thru it in a <Div> div.th {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}